# Iterators in Python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is a simple nested dictionary:

```
wordFrequency = {'bit':{1:3,2:4,3:19,4:0},'red':{1:0,2:0,3:15,4:0},'dog':{1:3,2:0,3:4,4:5}}
```

I am trying to work out the difference between what these two pieces of code do:

```
for word, innerDictionary in wordFrequency.iteritems():
    for fileNum, appearances in innerDictionary.iteritmes():
```

and

```
for fileNum, appearances in wordFrequency.get(word, {}).iteritems():
```

I know the first allows me to assign the keys and values of the inner dictionary to `fileNum` and appearances respectively.

However, I am unclear as to if the second piece of code does the same?

Comment: The first version iterates over all the values of `wordFrequency` while the latter iterates only on one value (the value of `word`)

Answer (score 0):

The following command :

```
for fileNum, appearances in wordFrequency.get(word, {}).iteritems():
```

Will give you only one value (of nested dictionaries) , but if you want it have a same effect like your preceding code ,As the `get()`'s function first argument must be a key of the dictionary you need to get the keys and put that code in a loop :

```
for word in  wordFrequency.keys() :
   for fileNum, appearances in wordFrequency.get(word, {}).iteritems():
```